# Ação após voltar aplicativo de segundo plano

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tenho uma webview no android que sempre verifica se há internet ao voltar do segundo plano verificando se foi mudado o estado de conexão caso esteja offline o app envia o usuário para uma tela de "reconecte-se e tente novamente" usando o código abaixo:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mWebView.onResume();
        if (isConnected(getApplicationContext())){
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, off.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Até ai tudo bem fiz uma versão para ios dessa webview mas não consegui reproduzir essa verificação quando o app retorna de segundo plano, como reproduzo esse "onresume" no swift do ios? (o código que verifica o estado de conexão já tenho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Rodrigo, apesar de o `viewDidAppear` ser uma possibilidade, esse método não chamado quando o app retorna de segundo plano. Na verdade `viewDidAppear` é chamado quando a view do ViewController se tornou visível. Isso nem sempre ocorre quando o app entra em primeiro plano. 
Se a intenção é de fato perceber quando o app recebe o foco, ao invés de depender do ciclo de vida de `UIViewController` (ex: viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear), o correto é utilizar os métodos do ciclo de vida da aplicação (`UIApplication`).
Nesse caso você pode utilizar `applicationWillEnterForeground`: ou `applicationDidBecomeActive`:. Eles são chamados no AppDelegate quando os eventos acontecem.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }
}
```

Caso no seu código faça mais sentido que esses callbacks sejam disparados em uma classe específica, como um UIViewController por exemplo, você pode utilizar o sistema de notificação.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o [ciclo de vida](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html) do iOS, o similar do `onResume` do Android, seria o `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        //sua lógica
}
```

Na documentação diz também sobre o `viewWillAppear()`, que seria um passo antes do `viewDidAppear()`. Veja qual te serve melhor!